Binding Enum to list of checkboxes
I want to understand, having an Enum with two values, how to display them on a ListBox with related CheckBoxes, and if they are checked or not
Here is the code:
public enum Type
{
  Type_A,
  Type_B
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={Extension:EnumBindingSource {x:Type Model:Type}}}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Source={Extension:EnumBindingSource {x:Type Model:Type}}}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Here's what I expect


Microsoft learn: How to bind to an enumeration (WPF .NET)

Your question lacks context: what is the current behavior (you only show what you expect) and context related code that allows a proper code review.

Firsts, declare an EnumHelper class:


namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class EnumHelper
    {
        public static Array GetValues(Type enumType)
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        }
    }

    public enum myEnum
    {
        Type_A,
        Type_B,
        Type_C,
        Type_D,
        Type_E
    }
}



Then, within your XAML (Let's say MainWindow.xaml), add a reference for your namespace [xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"]


<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">

  <!-- Window Content -->

</Window>



And then add this ObjectProvider inside your Windows.Resources


<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type local:EnumHelper}" x:Key="myEnumKey">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:myEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>



After which, you can finally use it like this:


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnumKey}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>



